# API Response and Error Message for Invalid Input Data Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, httprequest

Suppose I have a list of data stored in my database. So when the user types in invalid semesterId or invalid classId or invalid dayofWeek, how can I show error message and API response so that my backend will not crash?

Below is the request that are being sent out with invalid semesterId and wrong dayofWeek

```
//SEND REQUEST 
GET http://localhost:3000/basic/result?semesterId=2020100001&classId=4110000001&dayofWeek=9 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
```

This is my API

```
app.get('/basic/result', function (req, res, next) {

  const { classId, semesterId, dayofWeek } = req.query;
  //send the function to the backend 
  database.getDayLecture(classId, semesterId, dayofWeek, (error, result) => {
    const sortResult = backend.minHalls(result);
    if (error) {
      return next(error);
    }else {
        return res.json({
          result: sortResult,
        });
      }
  });
});
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you should add additional query params check.

```
app.get('/basic/result', function (req, res, next) {

  const queryParamsValidator = (classId, semesterId, dayofWeek) => {
    return true; // TODO: add your validation logic here
  }

  const { classId, semesterId, dayofWeek } = req.query;

  if (!queryParamsValidator(classId, semesterId, dayofWeek)) {
    return next('Params are invalid!'); // TODO: specify your error here
  }

  database.getDayLecture(classId, semesterId, dayofWeek, (error, result) => {
    const sortResult = backend.minHalls(result);

    if (error) {
      return next(error);
    } else {
      return res.json({
         result: sortResult
      });
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: May I know how to specify invalid data under validation logic? Isit `classId==null`?